# How to get symbols to revert back to starting position in AS3 flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi im trying to create a very simple drag and drop game in flash and I the scene to just loop round itself so say, if ( user does this) then go back to the beginning of the scene. but when I try this the symbols that the user has moved stay to where they have moved them too rather than returning to the position they were in at the start of the scene.

Can anyone explain a way to get the symbols to return to where they were at the begining of the scene once the if statement has completed?

Answer (score 0):

The following example will traverse the display list, storing symbols along with their initial positions in a `Dictionary`. When it's time to reset, just call the `resetToOriginalPositions` method, passing it the `Dictionary` that was created.

```
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var originalPositions:Dictionary;
if(!originalPositions)
{
    originalPositions = collectPositions(this);
}

function collectPositions(container:DisplayObjectContainer):Dictionary
{
    var positions:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);
    for(var i:int = 0; i < container.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var currentSymbol:DisplayObject = container.getChildAt(i);
        positions[currentSymbol] = new Point(currentSymbol.x, currentSymbol.y);

        // this will allow the symbols to be dragged/dropped
        currentSymbol.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickHandler);
        currentSymbol.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, clickHandler);
    }
    return positions;
}

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    var target:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
    if(e.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN)
    {
        target.startDrag();
    }
    else
    {
        target.stopDrag();
    }
}


function resetToOriginalPositions(positions:Dictionary):void
{
    for(var currentSymbol:Object in positions)
    {
        var position:Point = positions[currentSymbol];
        DisplayObject(currentSymbol).x = position.x;
        DisplayObject(currentSymbol).y = position.y;
    }
}

// this line should be called in your if statement that you already have set up
resetToOriginalPositions(originalPositions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Marcela's answer may work for you, but just in case you would like something a little simpler...you can store the original positions on a dynamic property of each object. When the condition you require is met to go back to the original positions you can call a function that resets the current x and y positions to the original ones.

```
//place in frame 1
dragObject1.originalY = dragObject1.y;
dragObject1.originalX = dragObject1.x;
dragObject2.originalY = dragObject2.y;
dragObject2.originalX = dragObject2.x;
//...rest of object posisitions


function resetObjectPositions()
{

    dragObject1.y = dragObject1.originalY;
    dragObject1.x = dragObject1.originalX;
    dragObject2.y = dragObject2.originalY;
    dragObject2.x = dragObject2.originalX;
    //...rest of object positions
}

//later in scene
if(condition)
{
        resetObjectPositions();//make sure to run this code before going back to frame one in the scene to use the original values;
}
```